# Unable to Expose Excel Data as a Data Service using WSO2 Integration Studio 8.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-micro-integrator

My use case is to Exposing Excel Data as a Data Service using WSO2 Integration Studio 8.2.0 ,but it didn't work .
This is my dataservice Configuration :

```
<data transports="http https local" serviceNamespace="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/json_sample" name="RESTDataService">
  <description>Exposing the data service as a REST service.</description>
    <config id="EXCEL">
    <property name="csv_datasource">C:/WSO2/biat.xls</property>
    <property name="csv_hasheader">true</property>
    <property name="csv_columnseperator">,</property>
    <property name="csv_startingrow">2</property>
    <property name="csv_maxrowcount">100</property>
    <property name="csv_headerrow">1</property>
  </config>
  <query id="Query1" useConfig="EXCEL">
    <sql />
    <result element="Products" rowName="Product">
      <element name="id" column="id" xsdType="string" requiredRoles="" />
      <element name="name" column="name" xsdType="string" requiredRoles="" />
      <element name="email" column="email" xsdType="string" requiredRoles="" />
      <element name="phone" column="phone" xsdType="string" requiredRoles="" />
    </result>
  </query>
  <operation name="Op1">
    <call-query href="Query1" />
  </operation>
  <resource method="GET" path="Products">
    <description />
    <call-query href="Query1" />
  </resource>
</data>
```

This is the error i got :

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in CSVQuery.runQuery.
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
```